# Bengali Fonts Rendering in java swing Incorrectly

Tags: java, swing, unicode, encoding, fonts

I am making a tools For Exam Seat plan. It is working fine in Netbeans Project also in Eclipse Project. So I made an executable jar of my tools, but when I run that jar, fonts are breaking and rendering incorrectly. Below I have added my sample code and images....

```
Font displayFont = new Font("SutonnyMJ", Font.BOLD, 22);
lblExamName.setFont(displayFont1);
lblExamName.setText("cixÿvi bvg:");
```

This image In Netbeans Project

[image]

And this one From jar file.

[image]

Comment: At a "guess", I would suggest that the Jar'ed version can not find the font.  Is it installed in the system or packaged with the Jar?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes installed.. I think this was encoding problem. Because when i set  `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8")`  it works.